# Using a HashMap to store the sensor addresses with tempetures on Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have started a small project to hopefully replace RPis running a Java library with Arduinos.
(I am normally working with Java, so not as familiar with C)

There are multiple temp sensors connected to the board. I read the values and want to store them with a reference to the sensor address. When a value changes, an update of all the sensors with their address and the temperatures is send to the server (hence I need the store to compare the values every 10 seconds).

I am trying to use the HashMap from Arduino Playground, as on a first look it seemed to do what I need and seems lightweight.

However, when reading the address of the temp sensor from a variable from the HashMap it doesn't return the right one (when there is some data pre-set in the hashmap):

```
      int strLen = sAddress.length();
      char *cAddress = (char *)malloc(strLen+1);
      sAddress.toCharArray(cAddress, strLen+1);

      byte position = sensorHashMap.getIndexOf(cAddress);
```

However, if I replace the *cAddress with:

```
      char *cAddress = "28aae25501412c";
```

it does find it. So what am I doing wrong?

My approach to store the temp values with the address as a reference might not be the best, and it seems that the code crashes later on when trying to update the value but I haven't gone down that far yet. If there is a better solution than I am very open to some suggestions off course.

The full code below:

```
#include <HashMap.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DS18B20.h>

char wifiSSID[] = "xxxx";
char wifiPassword[] = "xxxx";

unsigned long lastTempCheck = 0;

const byte HASH_SIZE = 10; // Max 10 (temp) sensors etc
HashType<char*, float> hashRawArray[HASH_SIZE];
HashMap<char*, float> sensorHashMap = HashMap<char*, float>( hashRawArray , HASH_SIZE );
int sensorsRegistered = 1;

WiFiClient client;
DS18B20 ds(5); // Is D1

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  WiFi.begin(wifiSSID, wifiPassword);

  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("---");

  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("Setup completed, ready to run...");

  // Test data
  sensorHashMap[0]("name", 18);
  sensorHashMap[1]("test", 200);
  sensorHashMap[2]("qwer", 1234);
  sensorHashMap[3]("28fffa6f51164ae", 123);
  sensorHashMap[4]("28aae25501412c", 456);
}

void loop() {
  // Duty cycle of the application
  delay(100);

  if ((millis() < lastTempCheck) || (millis() - lastTempCheck > 1000 * 10)) {
    // Verifying the HashMap works with the pre-set values.
    Serial.print("Checking pre-set values: ");
    Serial.println( sensorHashMap.getIndexOf("28fffa6f51164ae"), DEC );
    Serial.print("Checking sensor value: ");
    Serial.println( sensorHashMap.getValueOf("28fffa6f51164ae") );
    while (ds.selectNext()) {
      float temp = ds.getTempC();
      uint8_t address[8];
      ds.getAddress(address);
      String sAddress = "";
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sAddress += String(address[i], HEX);
      }

      int strLen = sAddress.length();
      char *cAddress = (char *)malloc(strLen+1);
      sAddress.toCharArray(cAddress, strLen+1);
      //char *cAddress = "28aae25501412c";

      byte position = sensorHashMap.getIndexOf(cAddress);
      Serial.print("Position: ");
      Serial.println( position);
      Serial.println( sensorHashMap.getIndexOf(cAddress), DEC );
      if (position < HASH_SIZE) {
        Serial.print("Updating sensor value, currently: ");
        Serial.println( sensorHashMap.getValueOf(cAddress));
        sensorHashMap[position](cAddress, temp); //ds.getTempC()
      } else {
        Serial.print("Creating sensor value, id is going to be ");
        Serial.println(sensorsRegistered);
        sensorHashMap[sensorsRegistered](cAddress, temp);
        sensorsRegistered++;
      }
      free(address);
    }
    lastTempCheck = millis();
  }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you simply call `sensorHashMap.getIndexOf(sAddress.c_str());` ?

Comment: use an array of structs. don't do small frequent dynamic allocations, because there is no memory manager to defragment the heap

Comment: sensorHashMap.getIndexOf(sAddress.c_str()); gives an invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Juraj can you give me a short example?

Comment: example of what? aray of structs? struct is like a class but usually without constructor and methods.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more precise. I used your suggestion and used (2) arrays, and it works. Thank you!